# Setting to Stay in Fullscreen/Slideshow Mode of photoviewer on Delete of Image

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-explorer, fullscreen, picasa

In windows 7, I use Picasa Photo Viewer in fullscreen mode to cull photos.  I can view them in full screen, nav with keyboard arrows and delete an image with del key (all while it stays fullscreen).

However, on my windows 8 laptop, I cant get it to behave the same.  On this, when I delete a photo, it leaves fullscreen mode after I hit delete.

I can't figure out what the difference is that is causing it.   Picasa viewer settings are identical.   I have edited recycle bin properties to not show the "are you sure you want to delete" dialog (which I thought was the culprit) but it's still happening.

Having many thousands of photo folders to cull through, I don't know if I can bear with this friction!

Any ideas how to resolve that, or what windows setting might help achieve what I am trying to do?